# Custom Fonts in Java

Tags: java, graphics, fonts, awt, custom-font

How to fix problem with custom fonts in Java?

For example, my app uses font, that isn't on all computers. Can I somehow include it in compiled executable and then call it from there, if it doesn't exists on clients computer?

What are other alternatives? I could make all fonts chars as images (before, in some graphics app) and then display image for each char... is it ok?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's an utility method I'm using to load a font file from a .ttf file (can be bundled):

```
private static final Font SERIF_FONT = new Font("serif", Font.PLAIN, 24);

private static Font getFont(String name) {
    Font font = null;
    if (name == null) {
        return SERIF_FONT;
    }

    try {
        // load from a cache map, if exists
        if (fonts != null && (font = fonts.get(name)) != null) {
            return font;
        }
        String fName = Params.get().getFontPath() + name;
        File fontFile = new File(fName);
        font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontFile);
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment
                .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();

        ge.registerFont(font);

        fonts.put(name, font);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.info(name + " not loaded.  Using serif font.");
        font = SERIF_FONT;
    }
    return font;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can include the font with you application and create it "on-the-fly"

```
InputStream is = this.getResourceAsStream(font_file_name);
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
```