# jasper report : print special characters

Tags: jasper-reports

I am printing an IReport report with JRPrintServiceExporter. 
I am using a tomcat server on Ubuntu.
Special character like "°" are not well printed, I am getting a "Â°".
"é" is printed "Â©"
Is there a way to display the good character?

If I preview it on a web browser and then print it, it is well printed, but if i print it directly with java javax.print.PrintService I am getting the accent problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093749/ukraine-cyrilic-characters-not-displaying-in-jasper-report-pdf  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739811/diacritic-chars-in-a-jasper-report-template, check encoding...

Comment: on another ubuntu system, the accents are well printed, maybe it 's a pb with a font not installed on the "failing" Ubuntu or on the java runtime of this ubuntu?

Comment: I can't, i have plenty of accents displayed I can't replace each one of them

Comment: i ll try, but I am confused by the fact that the same war is installed on the two ubuntu, one ubuntu prints well the accents, the other doesn't.

Comment: \u00E9 is printed "\u00E9", not è.

Comment: Could this be due to a different jdk? JDK1.8.0_25 is on the working ubuntu server, and JDK.1.8.0_45 is on the non working ubuntu server.